# Why is methyl iodide more dense than ethyl iodide, even though the latter has more carbon atoms?

Tags: organic-chemistry, halides, density

It is understood that more carbon atoms present in a hydrocarbon, the greater the density of the hydrocarbon.

But then why does $\mathrm{CH_{3}I}$ have a greater density than $\mathrm{C_{2}H_{5}I}$?

Comment: Because the iodides are not hydrocarbons, maybe?

Comment: @OscarLanzi If so then the effect of iodide should be pronounced on both ethyl iodide and methyl iodide equally and more on ethyl iodide as it is having one more  carbon?

Comment: Spacing between iodine atoms in different size molecules.

Answer (score -2):

For the same reason why a bucket of sand will weigh more than a bucket of rocks.
Smaller molecules will result in a more dense, thus more heavy substance.